# What collection should I use in a linq-to-sql query? Queryable vs Enumerable vs List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Imagine the following classes:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Underage
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I do something like this:

```
var underAge = db.Underage.Select(u => u.Age)   .ToList()/AsEnumerable()/AsQueryable() 

var result = db.Persons.Where(p => underAge.Contains(p.Age)).ToList();
```

What is the best option? If I call `ToList()`, the items will be retrieved once, but If I choose `AsEnumerable` or `AsQueryable` will they be executed everytime a person gets selected from database in the `Where()` (if that's how it works, I don't know much about what a database does in the background)?

Also is there a bigger difference when Underage would contain thousands of records vs a small amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None.

You definitely don't want `ToList()` here, as that would load all of the matching values into memory, and then use it to write a query for `result` that had a massive `IN (…)` clause in it. That's a waste when what you really want is to just get the matching values out of the database in the first place, with a query that is something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Persons
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL FROM 
  FROM Underage
  WHERE Underage.age = Persons.age
)
```

`AsEnumerable()` often prevents things being done on the database, though providers will likely examine the source and undo the effects of that `AsEnumerable()`. `AsQueryable()` is fine, but doesn't actually do anything in this case.

You don't need any of them:

```
var underAge = db.Underage.Select(u => u.Age);

var result = db.Persons.Where(p => underAge.Contains(p.Age)).ToList();
```

(For that matter, check you really do need that `ToList()` in the last line; if you're going to do further queries on it, it'll likely hurt them, if you're just going to enumerate through the results it's a waste of time and memory, if you're going to store them or do lots of in-memory operations that can't be done in Linq it'll be for the better).

Comment: So when I call the ToList in the second line, my program will only execute one query?

Comment: Yes, execute it once, do pretty much the equivalent of the SQL I show above, and produce a list. If however you just did `foreach` on it, it would do the SQL and then use each object as they came, which is often faster. If you didn't do `ToList()` or `foreach` then you would have another query that could be composed yet further. E.g. by adding another `Where()` or calling something like `Count()` where most of the work can be done in the database rather than grabbing it all up.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into that foreach, never used it with Linq

Comment: 98% of the time, if at all possible, you're end results with linq should be to either call an aggregate (`Count()`, `Max()` or something else that gives a single result) or to just `foreach` directly through the results. Only call a collection-producing method (`ToList()`, `ToDictionary()`, `ToLookup()`) if you **really** need that collection. There are some exceptions (in particular, **some** uses of `GroupBy` will be more efficient in-memory) but always default to pulling as little into memory at a go as you need to.

Comment: General rule is keep the object as close to it's original as possible for as long as possible.  DbSet  > IQueryable > IEnumerable > List/Array.  Only use one of the lower ones when there is a reason you need a lower one and a higher one won't work.

Comment: Great advice, will keep that in mind when I'm working with databases :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just leave your first query as

```
  var underage = db.Underage.Select(u => u.Age);
```

It will be of type IQueryable and it will not ping your database ( acutaly called deferred execution).   Once you actually want to execute a call to the database you can use a greedy operator such as **.ToList(), .ToArray(), .ToDictionary()**.  This will give your result variable an IEnumerable collection.

[See linq deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference between leaving the code like that and adding .AsQueryable()? I suppose not

Comment: Only that adding `AsQueryable()` can confuse issues when you later look at the code and wonder what it was there for.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use join to fetch the data.

```
var query = (from p in db.Persons
             join u in db.Underage
              on u.Age equals p.Age
             select p).ToList();
```

If you not use `.ToList()` in above query it return `IEnumerable` of type Person and actual data will be fetch when you use the object.

All are equally good ToList(), AsEnurmeable and Querable based on the scenario you want to use. For your case ToList looks good for me as you just want to fetch list of person have underage

Comment: Edited it, but I want to know what is best in my example above with Linq expressions.

Comment: There must be a difference. If I make it IQueryable, does it 'append' that query to the 2nd query or does it do a separate query like when I would use ToList()?

Comment: Joining would be incorrect if there were any duplicate ages in `underage`. To match the results of the query in the question you have to either have it as a known invariant that there are no duplicate ages, or use `Distinct()` on this.